# A problem in my homework

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, maximum-likelihood

[image]

It is a problem in my homework. I have worked out the MLE of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. $\sigma_1^{MLE} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iI_{(Xi>0})}{n}$+$\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iI_{(Xi>0)}} }{\sqrt{n}} *\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}-X_iI_{(Xi<0)}} }{\sqrt{n}}$

I wonder how to deal with the second term when n goes to infinty.

Comment: Please type out your image using MathJax, as you have already done with your attempt. Many users on the site cannot see images and they are not searchable so it will limit the reach of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you found MLE for $\sigma_1$ right! With $n\to\infty$, the term 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iI_{(X_i>0)}}{n} }\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n -X_iI_{(X_i<0)}}{n} }
$$
goes in probability due to LLN to a constant 
$$
\sqrt{\mathbb E\bigl[X_1I_{(X_1>0)}\bigr]}\cdot \sqrt{\mathbb E\bigl[X_1I_{(X_1>0)}\bigr]}.
$$
Here
$$
\mathbb E\bigl[X_1I_{(X_1>0)}\bigr]=\int_0^\infty x\cdot c\exp(-x/\sigma_1)\,dx = c\sigma_1^2 = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb E\bigl[-X_1I_{(X_1<0)}\bigr]=\int_{-\infty}^0 -x\cdot c\exp(x/\sigma_2)\,dx = c\sigma_2^2 = \frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2}
$$
So 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iI_{(X_i>0)}}{n} }\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n -X_iI_{(X_i<0)}}{n} } \xrightarrow{p} \frac{\sigma_1\sigma_2}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2}.
$$
And MLE for $\sigma_1$ is consistent:
$$
\sigma_1^{MLE}\xrightarrow{p}\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2} +\frac{\sigma_1\sigma_2}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2} = \sigma_1
$$

For asymptotic distribution of pair of estimates $(\sigma_1^{MLE},\sigma_2^{MLE})$ you probably need to use multivariate delta-method.

Comment: I think it can use fisher-information matrix to conclude the asymptotic distribution of the pair.

Comment: Would you like to help me for the problems?Thanks. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3578457/730191

Comment: @Kevinliu The first problem looks stange and I do not know what to do there. For the second, why did not you investigate log-likelihood function as for continuous parameter? The only difference is that the maximal point $\overline X$ can be non-integer and you should compare the values of log-likelihood in integer points left-right of the extreme point. So the answe definitely will be $[\overline X]$ under some conditions, and possibly $[\overline X+1]$, under the other conditions.